# C# Task.Run equivalent in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following code and it works fine in **.NET 4.5**

```
return Task.Run(async () => await MyAsyncMethodThatReturnsAnObject()).Result;
```

Now I need to make it run on **.NET 4.0**, so I came up with:

```
return Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(async () => { await MyAsyncMethodThatReturnsAnObject()}).Result;
```

But it's giving me this error:

> 'Task<object>' does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter and no
>   extension method 'GetAwaiter' acception the first argument of type
>   'Task<object>'

`MyAsyncMethodThatReturnsAnObject` is a factory method and its return type is `object`.

Comment: The delegate `async () =>  await MyAsyncMethodThatReturnsAnObject()` is equivalent to `() => MyAsyncMethodThatReturnsAnObject()` in both cases.

Comment: Better question is why are you doing that? your freeing up a thread to block another?

Comment: @spender Your suggestion made my code compile, which is great. However, when I made the same change in the caller it failed: `Cannot convert expression type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Something>' to return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<object>'`

Comment: @johnny5 Long story short: I had to wrap my async task in another thread to make it work as it was deadlocking.

Comment: How did you get your code to run on .NET 4.0 if .NET 4.0 does not have async/await. Did you use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`?

Comment: @AndreFeijo hmm seems shady, are you using EntityFramework in those Async Functions?

Comment: @AndreFeijo Then you shouldn't be blocking on an asynchronous operation, not creating new threads that just sit there doing nothing for the entire duration of that operation, or making the underlying operation synchronous all the way down, rather than doing half and half.  You're getting the worst of both worlds, and then more problems, and none of the benefits of either.

Comment: Note: If you are using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` you could just use `return TaskEx.Run(async () => await MyAsyncMethodThatReturnsAnObject()).Return;` the class `TaskEx` has the new static methods for Task in there like `Run(`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

async/await is .NET 4.5.
You need to install Microsoft.Bcl.Async for it to work in 4.

Comment: Note that if you are using `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` you can get the Run function back back by using `TaskEx.Run(` instead of `Task.Run(`

Answer (score -2):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<object>(() =>   
    MyAsyncMethodThatReturnsAnObject().Result,
    TaskScheduler.Default
).Result
```

Comment: [StartNew is dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), at minimum you should be passing in `TaskScheduler.Default` in to it to prevent bugs that cause your task code to run on the UI thread if your code is re-entrent.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the comment, I edited my answer to pass the `TaskScheduler.Default` to match the default behavior of `Task.Run`